# How to create a list of dataframes from a dataframe based on unique values in a column in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Can anyone tell me how to create a list of data frames from a data frame based on unique values of a column in the data frame in python

Answer (score 1):

Assume, your column is named `yourcol` and the data is stored in `df`. Use `df.query`:

```
listofdfs = [df.query('yourcol={}'.format(val)) for val in df[yourcol].unique()]
```

Or use `loc`:

```
listofdfs = [df.loc[df['yourcol']==val, :] for val in df[yourcol].unique()]
```

Other option would be groupby.

Have a look on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498463/python-splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-based-on-column-values-and/40498517), it was already answered.