# Create multiple pandas dataframes based on column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df I'd like to split into 5 (named df1 - df5) based on the value of one column (`origin`). I've tried `groupby`, and a few other things (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790790/splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498463/python-splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-based-on-column-values-and/40498517)) with no success.

My df looks like this

```
     origin t_id    Group   ids            ...
0    g2     300     group2  23, 54, 24     ...
1    g      300     group2  1, 89          ...
2    g3     300     group10 155, 4, 90     ...
3    g5     300     group11 38, 13, 45.    ...
4    g4     300     group2  2.             ...
```

Right now I have it broken up into multiple `.loc` statements for each unique value of `origin`, but there must be a cleaner, more concise way to do this.

Comment: It's hard to help with no illustration. Have a look at [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and then provide a sample of your data with the expected output

Comment: @AlexandreB. done

Comment: What is your expected output from the table above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do

```
a = []

for value in df['origin'].unique():
    a.append(df[df['origin']==value])
```

The array will contain the dataframes corresponding to the unique values.Let me know if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: This returns `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable`

Comment: Please try again. unique was supposed to be called as a function

Comment: that seems to run, but then `a` just prints all the data, not a list of df names.

Comment: To access one particular dataframe, you will have to do a[i]

Comment: is there a way to automatically name them in the same block of code. For example, df1-df5?

Comment: It would be possible if you can create python objects dynamically. I don't see the use of it.  You can always index them using the array. Another way to do this would be, using a dictionary. You could use 'df1','df2' as keys in the dict and generate the keys dynamically but it's important to keep in mind that the point of using pandas is to leverage parallelization which you lose if you start using dictionaries.