# Creating Multiple DataFrames from single DataFrame based on different values of single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 days of time series data with multiple columns in it. I have one single DataFrame which includes all 3 days data.  I want 3 different DataFrames based on Column name "Dates" i.e df["Dates"]

For Example:

Available Dataframe is: df

[image]

Expected Output: Based on Three different Dates

First DataFrame: df_23

[image]

Second DataFrame: df_24

[image]

Third DataFrame: df_25

[image]

I want to use these all three DataFrames separately for analysis.

I tried below code but I am not able to use those three dataframes (Rather I don't know how to use.) Can anybody help me to work my code better. Thank you.

[image]

Above code is just printing the DataFrame in three DataFrames that too not as expected as per code!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - splitting dataframe into multiple dataframes based on column values and naming them with those values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498463/python-splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-based-on-column-values-and)

Comment: @Datanovice: I tried using the similar code but I am not getting the expected output!

Comment: [You should not post code as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451)

Comment: @Parfait: Sure! I don't know about that.  Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure if your saving your variable into a csv or keep it in memory for further use,

you could pass each unique value into a dict and access by it's value :

```
    print(df)
     Cal  Dates
0    85     23
1    75     23
2    74     23
3    97     23
4    54     24
5    10     24
6    77     24
7    95     24
8    58     25
9    53     25
10   44     25
11   94     25



d = {}

for frame, data in df.groupby('Dates'):
    d[f'df{frame}'] = data


print(d['df23'])
    Cal  Dates
0   85     23
1   75     23
2   74     23
3   97     23
```

edit updated request :

```
for k,v in d.items():
    i = (v['Cal'].loc[v['Cal'] > 70].count())
    print(f"{v['Dates'].unique()[0]} --> {i} times")
23 --> 4 times
24 --> 2 times
25 --> 1 times
```

Comment: If I want to iterate through Index values and dictionary (d--> dictionary of df) How can I do that? For Example: If I want to count how many times 'cal' column values are exceeding '70' per day! Expected output from your dataframe should be:     on 23 --> 4 Times, on 24--> 2 times and on25--> 1Time

Comment: @Analyst updated for you - but this is basic for looping and working with python data types, I suggest you look at some basic tutorials for python and maybe search SO a little :) ask a new question if things get to complex but always post your data as text, show your code and paste any errors.

Comment: Yeah Thanks. I will do that from next for sure. I am trying out. I will post my code and error too for reference as well.  Thanks for suggestions. Appreciate for that.